# Runtime Error 49, Bad DLL calling convention in a D language DLL for Excel/VBA - What am I missing?

Tags: vba, dll, d, visual-d

I'm trying to get the simplest possible D-language DLL working from VBA in Excel.  I am using Visual D.  First, I copied the boilerplate example from https://wiki.dlang.org/Win32_DLLs_in_D, **DLLs with a C interface**, using the following code:

```
module DDLL;

import core.sys.windows.windows;
import core.sys.windows.dll;

__gshared HINSTANCE g_hInst;

extern (Windows)
BOOL DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, ULONG ulReason, LPVOID pvReserved)
{
    switch (ulReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            g_hInst = hInstance;
            dll_process_attach( hInstance, true );
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            dll_process_detach( hInstance, true );
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            dll_thread_attach( true, true );
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            dll_thread_detach( true, true );
            break;

        default:
    }
    return true;
}
```

The D application code I am trying to call from VBA is this:

```
module myfns;
export double testdd(double a, double b) { return a + b + 0; }
export int testi(int x) {return 42 + x ; }
export int testii(int a, int b) { return a + b + 0; }
```

The VBA code is:

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function testdd Lib "C:\Users\vvkozlov\sources\DDLL\Win32\Debug\DDLL.dll" _
    Alias "_D5myfns6testddFddZd" (ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double) As Double
Declare Function testi Lib "C:\Users\vvkozlov\sources\DDLL\Win32\Debug\DDLL.dll" _
    Alias "_D5myfns5testiFiZi" (ByVal x As Long) As Long
Declare Function testii Lib "C:\Users\vvkozlov\sources\DDLL\Win32\Debug\DDLL.dll" _
    Alias "_D5myfns6testiiFiiZi" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long

Public Sub test()

    Dim x As Long: x = 42000

    Debug.Print "two doubles: " & testdd(84#, -42#)
    Debug.Print "one long: " & testi(x)
    Debug.Print "two longs: " & testii(x, -x)

End Sub
```

Note I went in and fished out the mangled names from the generated DLL.

The testdd (two doubles) example works as expected, but both of the int examples result in a

```
Runtime Error 49, Bad DLL calling convention
```

in VBA.  At first, second, and third glance the argument declarations seem to be fine - `Long` on the VBA side, `int` in D.

Why does the `double` example work while the `int` fails?

Comment: it should prolly be extern(Windows) export in D too...

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe That did it

Answer (score 2):

Adam D Ruppe's advice was spot on.  The D application code now looks like

```
module myfns;
import std.conv;
extern(Windows) export double testdd(double a, double b) { return a + b + 0; }
extern(Windows) export int testi(int x) {return 42 + x ; }
extern(Windows) export int testii(int a, int b) { return a + b + 0; }
```

which also has the pleasant side effect of at least simplfying the name mangling (no, removing the Alias from the VBA code does not work).

The VBA now looks like

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function testdd Lib "C:\Users\vvkozlov\sources\DDLL\Win32\Debug\DDLL.dll" _
    Alias "_testdd@16" (ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double) As Double

Declare Function testi Lib "C:\Users\vvkozlov\sources\DDLL\Win32\Debug\DDLL.dll" _
    Alias "_testi@4" (ByVal x As Long) As Long

Declare Function testii Lib "C:\Users\vvkozlov\sources\DDLL\Win32\Debug\DDLL.dll" _
    Alias "_testii@8" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
```

And now on to `BSTR`, then maybe `SAFEARRAY`.  No `Variant`.